# Embed Jupyter HTML output in a web page

Tags: html, iframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I want to embed the HTML output of Jupyter, in my own web page. The reason for this is primarily, so that I can use Jupyter from my own webapp - and also access my research notebooks from anywhere in the world - via the internet.

A typical use case scenario would be that I click on a button on my page, and an iframe will be inserted in my page; Jupyter will then be launched at the backend (if not already running), and the output of Jupyter will be 'piped' to the iframe - so that I can use Jupyter from within my page.

The naive solution it appeared, was to use `<iframe>`, but there were two problems:

1. The iframe cross domain policy problem
2. Jupyter generated a one time authentication token when first launched

Is there anyway I can overcome these issues, so I can embed the output of Jupyter in my own web page?

Comment: you said jupyter, so i assume, you mean jupyter notebook... you will need to take look at https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to check nbconvert - https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert

there you have 2 options.

1. to use command line to run notebook and then to let some web server
   to server .html
2. to use python, and nbconvert library

here is short code :
if you want to show already generated:

`from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
    import nbformat
    from nbconvert import HTMLExporter
    from nbconvert.preprocessors.execute import CellExecutionError
    src_notebook = nbformat.reads(ff.read(), as_version=4)   #where ff is file opened with some open("path to notebook file")

    html_exporter = HTMLExporter()
    html_exporter.template_file = 'basic'  #basic will skip generating body and html tags.... use "all" to gen all..
    (body, resources) = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(src_notebook)
    print(body)   #body have html output`

if you want also to run notebook, then :

`from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor
    import nbformat
    from nbconvert import HTMLExporter
    from nbconvert.preprocessors.execute import CellExecutionError
    src_notebook = nbformat.reads(ff.read(), as_version=4)   #where ff is file opened with some open("path to notebook file")

    ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=50, kernel_name='python3')
    ep.preprocess(src_notebook, {})
    html_exporter = HTMLExporter()
    html_exporter.template_file = 'basic'  #basic will skip generating body and html tags.... use "all" to gen all..
    (body, resources) = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(src_notebook)
    print(body)   #body have html output`

Comment: +1 for your input. This sounds like what I'm trying to do. I'll try it, and if it works, I'll accept your answer. BTW, it looks like you're importing some non standard modules (to get access to nbformat and HTMLExporter) - which module(s?) are you importing from? Thanks

Comment: i added imports... its actualy snap from app.. just keep in mind, execution of notebooks is not fast... i usually run  some cron in background to run notebooks   , and script is only converting without execution...

Comment: Sorry, I have **_absolutely no idea_** what you mean by your statement: "i added imports... its actualy snap from app.". Please clarify.

Comment: The most concise and simple example I've ever seen for this.  So tiered of reading extensive docs with no simple overview...  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly do that using the `html_embed`  pre-processor:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert  --to html_embed  Annex.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook Annex.ipynb to html_embed
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/filters/datatypefilter.py:41: UserWarning: Your element with mimetype(s) dict_keys(['image/pdf']) is not able to be represented.
  mimetypes=output.keys())
[NbConvertApp] Writing 2624499 bytes to Annex.html
```

Strangely, I could not find a direct reference in the [manual](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=html_embed&check_keywords=yes&area=default) from nbconvert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ipython nbconvert - -to html notebook.ipynb to obtain the html code for the same.
Here is a guide on how to do it Blogging with the IPython notebook - [see here](http://blog.fperez.org/2012/09/blogging-with-ipython-notebook.html)

If your website is writing in python the use python embed docs
Also this Tutorial - [see here](http://onsnetwork.org/eimd/2014/08/07/iframes-for-ipython/)

or use kyso.io
Here is how to embed Jupyter using Kyso platform - [see here](https://blog.kyso.io/posts/embed-jupyter-notebooks)

(disclaimer - I’m a founder of kyso)